# Scrolling Banners tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos, apple-tv

I am implementing a tvOS app. Most of the controls are implemented and I have also made use of the Focus Engine. But there is one control which seems like a banner and it moves down when it is focused. Can anyone please confirm if it is customized CollectionViewCell. If yes, how does it animate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element is a part of [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbar).

Comment: I need the same banner so is it implemented within UITabBar..??